# ¿Qué tipo de palabra es "todos" en la oración "Nosotros todos hemos estado estudiando"?

Tags: pronombres, adjetivos, sintaxis

He leído que "todos" puede ser considerado determinante, pronombre indefinido y que a veces tiene "valor adverbial".

¿Qué tipo de palabra es **todos** en estas oraciones?

> Nosotros todos hemos estado estudiando.

> Todos nosotros hemos estado estudiando.

Esta oración ya tiene un pronombre, por lo que supongo que no será un pronombre indefinido aquí. ¿O me equivoco?

Comment: ¿Es posible que conforma con la definición del DLE de "aposición"?, o sea un "apositivo"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo interpreto que es un adjetivo. Está afinando el significado de "nosotros" para asegurar que son todos los posibles.

"Todo" como adverbio es un caso menos frecuente, como en:

"Soy todo oídos"

Aquí puedes ver una explicación muy detallada de las diferentes posibilidades.
http://zonaele.com/todo-toda-todos-y-todas/

Comment: Yo no lo veo como un adjetivo... Para mi "todos" es otro pronombre, o quizás un sustantivo puede ser en este caso..

Comment: Según el uso, puede ser adjetivo, pronombre o adverbio. En este caso es la definición 1 del diccionario de la RAE http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZXVCOJQ, creo yo, que es un adjetivo.

Comment: @AdrianaHernández yo tampoco lo veo como adjetivo ya que la frase se puede cambiar a "̶N̶o̶s̶o̶t̶r̶o̶s̶  todos hemos estado estudiando" sin que cambie para nada su sentido. Pienso que es pronombre.

Answer (score 2):

La primera acepción de la palabra *[todo, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZxVCoJq)* en el DLE nos da la respuesta exacta a esta pregunta:

> 1. adj. indef. Indica la totalidad de los miembros del conjunto denotado por el sintagma nominal al que modifica. U. con sintagmas nominales definidos en plural. *Leyó todos los artículos. Todos ellos acudieron a la cita.* U. a veces en lenguaje literario tras el nombre. *Sus hijos todos.*

Como podemos ver, la entrada del diccionario nos da incluso dos ejemplos muy similares a los de la pregunta. Por tanto, se trata de un **adjetivo indefinido**.

Answer (score 1):

A primera vista me parece un pronombre. Del mismo modo que puede haber un doble determinante, como en "todos los participantes", al omitir el sustantivo y usar pronombres ninguno de los dos debería ser "privilegiado" como para ser uno pronombre y otro adjetivo. Lo cierto es que es complicado decidir.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that "todos" is a pronoun in apposition to another pronoun, "nosotros". Eliminate either one and the remaining one has the same function: subject of the sentence, as Adriana pointed out. Nouns or other elements in apposition exercise the same function in a sentence. The DLE defines *aposición* as "un grupo nominal" que "sigue inmediatamente a otro elemento de la misma clase con el que forma una unidad sintáctica."